# Is there a way of not showing anything other than the date text on 'input type=datetime-local'

Tags: html

I have removed the date icon with the following css

```
input[type="datetime-local"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
            display: none;
}
```

This resolves my problems for chrome but in mozilla everytime the input is clicked a date-picker opens up. Also, a clear icon is visible whenever a date value is entered. Is there a way to not show these...

PS: I only care about modern browsers

[image: firefox date picker]

Comment: Can you share Demo link?

Comment: Demo is: 
1- Write html: <input type="datetime-local"> . 
2- Open it in firefox. 
3- Observe that it shows date-picker when you click on it.